# mongoose/mongodb I am able to post but not get data. Only returns status code 500 without error

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js

This is a next.js app with mongoose connected to a mongodb atlas server. I only get status code 500 from a fetch call but I know there is good data in my mongodb atlas. I use the same model to post just fine. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

here is my connection component:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const connection = {};

const dbConnect = async () => {
  if (connection.isConnected) {
    return;
  }

  const db = await mongoose.connect(process.env.mongodb.uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });

  connection.isConnected = db.connections[0].readyState;
};

export default dbConnect;
```

my model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const EmployeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  companyId: {
    type: String,
    required: [true],
    maxlength: [200],
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "A first name is required"],
    maxlength: [50, "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters"],
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "A last name is required"],
    maxlength: [50, "Last name cannot be longer than 50 characters"],
  },
});

module.exports =
  mongoose.models.Employee || mongoose.model("Employee", EmployeeSchema);
```

Lastly, my endpoint:

```
import dbConnect from "../../../utils/dbConnect";
import Employee from "../../../models/Employee";

dbConnect();

export default async (req, res) => {
  const { method } = req;

  switch (method) {
    case "GET":
      try {
        const employee = Employee.find({});
        if (!employee) {
          res.status(400).json({ success: false });
        }
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: employee });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, data: error });
      }
      break;
    case "POST":
      try {
        const employee = Employee.create(req.body);
        if (!employee) {
          res.status(400).json({ success: false });
        }
        res.status(201).json({ success: true, data: employee });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, data: error });
      }
      break;
    default:
      res.status(400).json({ success: false });
      break;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

turns out, the error was that my fetch needed to be an await.

const employee = Employee.find({}); ----> const employee = await Employee.find({});